# How to sort an array by the value of an object within a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I am trying to order an array of objects, in this context houses, and I am trying to write a function where users can order the array of houses by the distance of a landmark. Say I have the following data returned from an API that I am calling through AJAX:

```
"data" : [
    {
        'id' : 123,
        'address' : '12 street name',
        'city' : 'City Name',
        'landmarks' : [
            {
                'name' : 'landmark one',
                'distanceInMiles' : 0.6
            },
            {
                'name' : 'landmark two',
                'distanceInMiles' : 0.4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'id' : 345,
        'address' : '22 street name',
        'city' : 'City Name',
        'landmarks' : [
            {
                'name' : 'landmark one',
                'distanceInMiles' : 0.2
            },
            {
                'name' : 'landmark three',
                'distanceInMiles' : 0.1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'id' : 456,
        'address' : '28 street name',
        'city' : 'City Name',
        'landmarks' : [
            {
                'name' : 'landmark six',
                'distanceInMiles' : 8.2
            },
            {
                'name' : 'landmark seven',
                'distanceInMiles' : 1.6
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I already have some code that will return the houses that contain a particular landmark, e.g. filter this array to return houses that have the landmark "landmark one", and I store that filtered data into a separate array. But I now want to go a step further and order my filtered array of results based on the `distanceInMiles` value against the selected landmark.

So, sticking with this context I am trying write some code that will return the two houses with the address "22 street name" first and the house with the "12 street name" address second, since the "22 street name" house is closer to landmark one than the other.

I'm using _loadash as my utility library, but struggling to understand how to sort the filtered array by the "landmark one" distance. Any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `r.sort(function(a,b){return a.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles  - b.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles; })`

Comment: @dandavis Can you put that in an answer and explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [
 {
  "id" : 123,
  "address" : "12 street name",
  "city" : "City Name",
  "landmarks" : [
   {
    "name" : "landmark one",
    "distanceInMiles" : 0.6
   },
   {
    "name" : "landmark two",
    "distanceInMiles" : 0.4
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id" : 345,
  "address" : "22 street name",
  "city" : "City Name",
  "landmarks" : [
   {
    "name" : "landmark one",
    "distanceInMiles" : 0.2
   },
   {
    "name" : "landmark three",
    "distanceInMiles" : 0.1
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id" : 456,
  "address" : "28 street name",
  "city" : "City Name",
  "landmarks" : [
   {
    "name" : "landmark six",
    "distanceInMiles" : 8.2
   },
   {
    "name" : "landmark seven",
    "distanceInMiles" : 1.6
   }
  ]
 }
];

function sortByLandmarkDistance(name) {
    var getDistance = function(house) {
        var minDistance = Infinity;

        for(var i = 0; i < house.landmarks.length; ++i)
            if(house.landmarks[i].name === name)
             minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, house.landmarks[i].distanceInMiles);

        return minDistance;
    };

    return data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return getDistance(a) - getDistance(b);
    });
}
    
// Sort houses by distance from 'landmark one'
var sorted = sortByLandmarkDistance('landmark one');
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sorted, null, '    ') + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested locally and this is working as I would like it to. Many thanks to all the other answers too, I'm sure they work as well but I've not had chance to read through them all properly! Everyone's help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This implementation let you decide which landmark you want to "order by", most of the other answers assume it's the first one in the array `... landmarks[0] ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method with a custom sort function. Sort looks for a `-1`, `0`, or `1`. So all you have to do is subtract distance `b` from `a` and viola!

```
function sortLandmarkDistanc1 (a, b) {
    return a.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles - b.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles;
}
data.sort(sortLandmarkDistanc1);
```

```js
var data = [
  {
   'id' : 123,
   'address' : '12 street name',
   'city' : 'City Name',
   'landmarks' : [
    {
     'name' : 'landmark one',
     'distanceInMiles' : 0.6
    },
    {
     'name' : 'landmark two',
     'distanceInMiles' : 0.4
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   'id' : 345,
   'address' : '22 street name',
   'city' : 'City Name',
   'landmarks' : [
    {
     'name' : 'landmark one',
     'distanceInMiles' : 0.2
    },
    {
     'name' : 'landmark three',
     'distanceInMiles' : 0.1
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   'id' : 456,
   'address' : '28 street name',
   'city' : 'City Name',
   'landmarks' : [
    {
     'name' : 'landmark six',
     'distanceInMiles' : 8.2
    },
    {
     'name' : 'landmark seven',
     'distanceInMiles' : 1.6
    }
   ]
  }
 ];

function sortLandmarkDistanc1 (a, b) {
 return a.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles - b.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles;
}
/* ignore this, just for showing results */
function repeatString(a,c){out="";for(var d=0;d<c;d++)out+=a;return out}
function dump(a,c){c="number"!==typeof c?0:c;var d=typeof a,b=d;switch(d){case "number":case "boolean":b+=": "+a;break;case "string":b+="("+a.length+'): "'+a+'"';break;case "object":if(null===a)b="null";else if("[object Array]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(a)){b="array("+a.length+"): {\n";for(d=0;d<a.length;d++)b+=repeatString("   ",c)+"   ["+d+"]:  "+dump(a[d],"none",c+1)+"\n";b+=repeatString("   ",c)+"}"}else{sContents="{\n";cnt=0;for(var e in a)sContents+=repeatString("   ",c)+"   "+e+":  "+
dump(a[e],"none",c+1)+"\n",cnt++;sContents+=repeatString("   ",c)+"}";b+="("+cnt+"): "+sContents}}return b};
/*-----------------------*/
document.getElementById('before').innerHTML = dump(data);
document.getElementById('after').innerHTML = dump(data.sort(sortLandmarkDistanc1));
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
<h1>Before</h1>
<pre id="before"></pre>
        </td>
      <td>
<h1>After</h1>
<pre id="after"></pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty much exact example of how to do this here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

So, in your case, the function would look something like this:

```
var data = getArrayFromAJAXHere();

data.sort(function(a,b){return a.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles - b.landmarks[0].distanceInMiles; })
```

This will order the array by distance to location in ascending order.

Comment: you should never rely on the shitty website (w3schools). Use MDN instead : [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @Apolo,  I have heard this about them, but the data they had in this case seems to be correct when I compare it to MDN.  What is the specific case where the website is wrong?

Comment: and also, the W3Schools name is foolish and misleading, because they have nothing to do with W3C which IS authoritative for web tech

Comment: @Apolo.  I agree with your statement about having nothing to do with w3c.  If I am researching something myself, I usually refer to SO, w3.org, or MDN.  The only reason I used w3schools was they had the exact example I needed very easy to find.  Thank you for the comments.  I will keep them in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of the values paired with an array counting them (i.e. `[0, 1, 2, ...]`). The code I supply assumes your (filtered) array is of this format:

```
filtered = [
{
    id: 123,
    address: "12 Street Name",
    city: "City Name",
    landmark: {
        name: "landmark One"
        //and other landmark properties
    }
}, {
    id: 456,
    //and so on...
```

Code:

```
var content = [];
var order = [];
var x;
for (x = 0; x < filtered.length; x++) {
    content[x] = filtered[x].landmark.distanceInMiles;
    order[x] = x;
}
var sorted = false;
var y;
while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;
    for (x = 1; x < content.length; x++) {
        if (content[x-1] > content[x]) {
            sorted = false;
            y = content[x];
            content[x] = content[x-1];
            content[x-1] = y;
            y = order[x];
            order[x] = order[x-1];
            order[x-1] = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the array `order` should contain the correct order of the houses, smallest to largest.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering and sorting:

```
// first you call the filter function that will return a new filtered array
var myFilteredAndSorteredArray = arr.filter(function(item) {
  // here, you must return true if the item has the "landmark one"
  // the map function returns a new array converting for what you're returning
  // so, you return their names and use the indexOf to see if it has "landmark one"
  return item.landmarks.map(function(land) { return land.name; }).indexOf("landmark one") > -1;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  // now you sort the filtered array
  // so, you use the same map function to get exactly the "landmark one"
  var landA = a.landmarks[a.landmarks.map(function(land) { return land.name; }).indexOf("landmark one")];
  var landB = b.landmarks[b.landmarks.map(function(land) { return land.name; }).indexOf("landmark one")];
  // you always compare the second parameter with the first one
  // since you want to return the smaller distance, you use the < operator
  return landB.distanceInMiles < landA.distanceInMiles;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash, you could use [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) as a chain:

```
_(data)
    .filter(function(item) {
        return _.any(item.landmarks, {
            name: 'landmark one'
        });
    })
    .sortBy(function(item) {
        return _.find(item.landmarks, {
            name: 'landmark one'
        }).distanceInMiles;
    })
    .value();
```